# How do I automatically reset tcolorbox numbering with each UNnumbered section?

Tags: numbering, tcolorbox

I'm using tcolorbox for exercises, and I'd like to automatically restart the numbering at each section, including unnumbered sections.

I'm using documentclass `[book]` and have several chapters.

At the moment, the counter is automatically reset for numbered `\section`, but not for unnumbered `\section*`

I even tried `\setcounter{tcbcounter}{0}` in order to manually set the counter to 0 after each section, but even that doesn't work, unless the code is inserted within a box rather than between boxes.

I've realized that adding `\stepcounter{section}` before starting every single section following an unnumbered section does the job (as shown in the MWE), but that is far from efficient and automatic.

Here's a MWE where box 3 and 4 should be numbered 1 and 2, respectively :

```
\documentclass[A4]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{mybox}[2][]{%
    title=Mybox~\thetcbcounter: #2, #1}
    
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}

\begin{mybox}{A box with title}
This is a numbered box.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{}
This is a numbered box without title.
\end{mybox}

\section*{Unnumbered section}

\begin{mybox}{Another box with title}
This is a numbered box. 
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{}
This is a numbered box without title.
\end{mybox}

\section*{Second unnumbered section}
\stepcounter{section}
\begin{mybox}{A third box with title}
This is a numbered box.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{}
This is a numbered box without title.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: @Mensch it's [book]. Sorry, I meant to include it in the code.

Comment: Actually, it IS in my code, how comes it is not shown ?

Comment: There was a newline missing after your three back ticks ... I corrected your code.

Comment: Great, thanks. At least I know what to do in the future !